# What is the [shortcut/other way] for go to definition in Eclipse+Pydev

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I used to use `WingIde`, where in a shortcut(f4, default) which I used quite often was Goto definition, which will open the definition file, and take me to it. Is there a similar shortcut for eclipse+pydev?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For Aptana Pydev, you have "[Go To Definition](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_gotodef.html)": <kbd>F3</kbd>
([Andrew Falanga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/988207/andrew-falanga) [comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107301/what-is-the-the-shortcut-other-way-for-go-to-definition-in-eclipsepydev/2107336?noredirect=1#comment40836325_2107336) that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> allows you to return to the point you left)

> The 'go to definition' actions enables you to get to a given definition.
>
> - It works well on 'self' tokens
> - It can work on methods / attributes from parameters (as the image below shows).

[image: goto definition]

Comment: Originally, I commented, asked a question really, as to what's the shortcut key(s) to return to the point you left.  I still haven't found it by googling, probably just not typing the right search words, but on a whim I thought I'd try Alt+<left_arrow> and it worked.  So, if you're like me and find your way here to find the answer to F3, the next question you might have is answered with Alt+<left_arrow>

Comment: @AndrewFalanga good find. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 12):

As others answered, F3 is the way to go, but going a bit further, you might also want to take a look at ctrl+shift+t to browse all the tokens available and ctrl+shift+r to browse all the files.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean "go to where a method/class/variable" is defined, in Eclipse, it is <kbd>F3</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Although the question is pretty time-barred, maybe this more general approach will help others looking for specific short-cuts in eclipse.

Help - Key Assist... opens a list of all available short-cuts, alphabetically sorted by description. ("Open Declaration" was the one looked for here.)

Window - Preferences - General - Keys lets you edit the short-cuts.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does not work when you set `MSVC scheme`. In eclipse mars go to
`Windows->preferences` then go to `General->keys` (or in `type filter text` type `keys`) then in `Keys` in `type filter text` type `definition`. Then you shall see in `command` below `Python Go To Definition`. In `Binding` text edit you can then set any shortcut you want.