# ColdFusion IDE equivalent to Visual Studio's "go to definition" and "find usages"

Tags: coldfusion, cfeclipse

Do any of the ColdFusion IDEs/IDE plugins allow you to perform actions similar to Visual Studio's *go to definition* and *find usages* (some details of which are on [this page](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/24/search-and-navigation-tips-tricks-with-visual-studio.aspx))?

For example, in one `.cfc` file I might have:

```
<cfset variables.fooResult = CreateObject(
    "component",
    "Components.com.company.myClass").fooMethod()>
```

And in `myClass.cfc` I have:

```
<cffunction name="fooMethod" access="public">
    <!-- function body -->
</cffunction>
```

If I have my cursor set over `.fooMethod` in the first file, a *go to definition* action should place me on the declaration of that method in `myClass.cfc`.

At present I'm using the [CFEclipse](http://cfeclipse.org/) plugin for Eclipse to view some legacy ColdFusion.

Comment: Is F3 what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107301/what-is-the-the-shortcut-other-way-for-go-to-definition-in-eclipsepydev and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348567/jump-to-method-call-from-method-definition-in-eclipse-java-perspective

Comment: @Miguel-F - I don't think so. I've updated my question with more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CFEclipse doesn't have this functionality, partly because CFML is a dynamic language with a fair bit of complexity parsing-wise.

You can use regex searching to get you most of the way there in most cases.

### Function Definitions

To find a function definition, most times searching for...

```
(name="|ion )methodname
```

...is enough, and quicker than the more thorough form of:

```
(<cffunction\s+name\s*=\s*['"]|\bfunction\s+)methodname
```

### Function Calls

To find a function call, against just do:

```
methodname\s*\(
```

Though against you might need to be more thorough, with:

```
['"]methodname['"]\s*\]\s*\(
```

...if bracket notation has been used.

You might also want to check for [cfinvoke](http://cfdocs.org/cfinvoke) usage:

```
<cfinvoke[^>]+?method\s*=\s*['"]methodname
```

Of course, neither of these methods will find if you have code that is:

```
<cfset meth = "methodname" />
<cfinvoke ... method="#meth#" />
```

...nor any other form of dynamic method names.

If you *really* need to be thorough and find all instances, it's probably best to search for the method name alone (or wrapped as `\bmethodname\b`), and manually walk through the code for any variables using it.

Answer (score 3):

IF you use

```
<cfset c = new Components.com.company.myClass()>
<cfset variables.fooResult = c.fooMethod()>
```

I believe in CFBuilder you can click Ctrl and the CFC class and method will turn into a hyperlink.  See "Code insight" on http://www.adobe.com/ca/products/coldfusion-builder/features.html  It works when it work, it doesn't when mapping is incorrect or certain syntax may not be supported.  I'm not sure if they support the `CreateObject()` way.

There's no find usage as CF is not a static language.  However, the Find can find what you need most of the time unless the code invokes method dynamically or uses `Evaulate()`